# Bottom corner radius effect with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

my previous question was closed, but I'm sure I was misunderstood. I'll copy that question again, so please don't close is, as far as I have a specific question.

I'm going to build a tabbed menu like this:

[image]

So I wonder maybe you can suggest if there is a way to build it with pure CSS maybe, or any other way, so the code and css is clean. And there might be 10 - 15 tabs in a row.

There might be drop down too.

So the html part might look like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">Some Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Some Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Some Text</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="">Some Text</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Some Text</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Some Text</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

thanks!!

EDIT

**I have no problem building tabs and I know how to make top radius on menu item, and gradient with CSS, but have no idea how to achieve bottom "corner radius" effect on the selected menu item.**

Is it possible to build a menu like this with only CSS? or I HAVE to use images anyway?

all samples and examples on the web are rounded at the bottom but don't have effect like this on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Mikey, this is a surprisingly tough thing to do in CSS, since there's no way to do exclusions.

One solution is to use before and after psuedo elements with a transparent background and a border that is thick enough to act as the bottom outer curved portion. Here's a simple two-color example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/udfJc

The key portion here is to have the border color be red. You can hide the overflow of this element to tighten up the bottom line if you want. Given your design, this technique should work with minimal tweaking.

Comment: I believe this technique is not possible with gradients.

Comment: That's true, Christoph. However, in the design above it looks like the gradient could end before the outward flange begins. If this is the case (or if the designer is willing to extend the solid color) then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the active tab and inactive tabs' background colors are not gradient, it is possible to implement it by using pure CSS. [See here](http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/).

However, if tabs have gradient background colors, like the screenshot you posted, then images are needed.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans said, using pure css for that would be tough (and there is that gradient problem). I believe most website use images and, if you want it simple, yes, use images.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS4 will support this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-4/#border-corner-shape) but i'm sure you don't have the time for now :P
The best solution that i could think is making your tab-title `position:relative` than adding :before and :after content with position:relative with background-images that contain your graphic elements. For extra optimization i would recomand to put them in a [sprite](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). So:

```
.tab-title{position:relative;} 
.tab-title:before,.tab-title:after{content:" "; width:5px; height:5px; position:absolute; backgrund-image:url(tab_graphic_elem.png);}
.tab-title:after{background-position:5px 0;}
```

Comment: you mean borders module lvl4, there is no such thing as css4. And w3schools is probably the [worst source](http://w3fools.com/) to link to...

Comment: i know enough to see that what i linked is valide for what i wanted to say. and there will be such thing as css4 that will integrate borders module lvl4.

Comment: well, after css2.1 all parts of the css spec are developed in modules. Some happen to have the version number 3, others have other numbers. Animations have been introduced to "css3" but are at "level 1". Since the developmentspeed of the modules differs you cannot speak of [css4](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Ko0) or anything like this. And please read the article about w3schools. There are several better resources out there.

Answer (score -1):

yep it possible
 border radius u have mention in em or % like this.

```
border-radius: 10px/30px; /* horizontal radius / vertical radius */
border-radius: 1em/5em;
```

u ckeck like dis may be u'll get by using dis way

Comment: sry milky.. i agree with christoph.. it which hans said possible when use single color only. for gradient it's not possible..

Answer (score -2):

Use this **CSS BORDER RADIUS GENERATOR**...

http://border-radius.com/

It will generator the css as far as your requirement..